# Destructure React component into "building blocks"

Tags: reactjs

I am using `IonSlides` in my app but due to a [bug](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/18782) with them, dynamically adding slides can prove difficult.
Because `IonSlides` is built upon SwiperJS, it has some methods to add and remove slides. The downside to those is that they take a string with HTML in it. In my case, I need to be able to pass in JSX elements so that I can use event listeners on them. Originally, this was my code:

```
private bindEvents(el: JSX.Element): void {
    if (el.props.children) { //Checking if the element actually has children
        const children = this.toArray(el.props.children); //If it has only 1 child, it is an object, so this just converts it to an array

        children.forEach((c: any) => {
            if (!c.props) return; //Ignore if it has no props

            const propNames = this.toArray(Object.keys(c.props)); //Get the key names of the props of the child
            const el = $(`.${c.props.className}`); //Find the element in the DOM using the class name of the child

            propNames.forEach(p => { //Binds the actuall events to the child.
                if (Events[p] !== undefined) {
                    el.on(Events[p], c.props[p]); //`c.props[p]` is the handler part of the event
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Which was called through:

```
appendSlide(slides: JSX.Element | JSX.Element[]): void {
    if (this.slideRef.current === null) return;

    this.slideRef.current.getSwiper().then(sw => {
        slides = this.toArray(slides);

        slides.forEach(s => {
            sw.appendSlide(ReactDOMServer.renderToString(s));

            this.bindEvents(s);
        });
    });
}
```

This worked perfectly when appendSlide was called with an IonSlide:

```
x.appendSlide(<IonSlide>
    <div onClick={() => console.log("Clicked!")}</div>Click me!</IonSlide>
```

If you clicked the div, it would print "Clicked!".

However, if you pass in a custom component, it breaks. That is because the custom component does not show the children under `props`. Take this component:

```
interface Props {
    test: string,
}

const TestSlide: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {

    return (
        <IonSlide>
            <div>
               {props.string}
            </div>
        </IonSlide>
    );
}
```

If you were to print that component's props, you get:

```
props: {test: "..."}
```

rather than being able to access the children of the component, like I did in the `bindEvents` function.

There's two ways that I could do fix this. One is getting the JS object representation of the component, like this (I remember doing this ages ago by accident, but I can't remember how I got it):

```
{
  type: 'IonSlide',
  props: {
    children: [{
      type: 'div',
      props: {
        children: ["..."],
      },
    }
  },
}
```

or, a slight compromise, destructuring the custom component into its "building blocks". In terms of `TestSlide` that would be destructuring it into the `IonSlide` component.

I been trying out things for a few hours but I haven't done anything successful. I would really appreciate some help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever reason that someone needs this, I found you can do `el.type(el.props)` where `el` is a JSX element.
This creates an instance of the element so under `children` instead of seeing the props, you can see the actual child components of the component.